# Color tables cells in ppt using python

Tags: python, python-pptx

So I have a excel which contains a table like this:

[image]

**I want to get the same table in powerpoint using Python**

**Work Done till now**:

1. Read the excel to python and store in pandas df
2. Add df to powerpoint

**Code for the same effort:**

```
from pd2ppt import df_to_table
import pandas as pd
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.util import Inches

path =r"Sample PPT.pptx"
prs = Presentation(path)
title_slide_layout = prs.slide_layouts[5]
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(title_slide_layout)
title = slide.shapes.title
title.text = "Summary Table"

top = Inches(1.5)
left =Inches(0.25)
width =Inches(9.25)
height= Inches(5.0)


df_to_table(slide, df,left, top, width, height)
```

**All I need is how to do color formatting in this table using Python?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each cell in a PowerPoint table has its own *fill*, which can do everything other `FillFormat` objects can do::

```
from pptx.dml.color import RGBColor

cell = table.cell(0, 0)  # ---or whatever cell you choose---
fill = cell.fill
fill.solid()
fill.fore_color.rgb = RGBColor(0xFA, 0x00, 0x37)
```

The `FillFormat` object interface is further described in the documentation here:
https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/dml.html#fillformat-objects

Comment: Thanks for the reply!! one clarification..here your have done `table.cell` now my table is in a pandas df, how to fill `cell` value. If I do this `cell = df.iloc[0,0]` then `cell.fill` gives me this error `'str' object has no attribute 'fill'`

Comment: The return value of `table.cell()` (`cell` in code above) is a `_Cell` object, which provides the properties and methods needed to change the PowerPoint table cell. If you assign `df.iloc[0, 0]` to `cell` you lose that `_Cell` object and the ability to change the table cell. Maybe you want `cell.text = df.iloc[0, 0]`.

Comment: I tried `cell.text = df.iloc[0, 0]` it gives me an error `NameError: name 'cell' is not defined`

Comment: @RahulAgarwal I can't diagnose your code without seeing it. Perhaps post the code in a new question and tag it with "python-pptx" and I'll see it.